# How to get ServletConfig within Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets

try to autowired `ServletConfig` into current application, not `ServletContext` because an API ask for it.

I know user can get ServletContext by a ServletConfig servlet but how to do the other way around or taken from spring application

Comment: Where is it you need the `ServletConfig`? And what do you need it for? Only bootstrap classes (ie. configuration) should really use it.

Comment: `ServletConfig` is passed to the Servlet's `init` method and it shouldn't be used anywhere else.

Comment: Can you share the reason why you need this? Maybe there is another workaround.

Comment: @Marcel Stör Thanks everyone, it just the one of the `API`s from an old external lib but called by this spring application ask for a `javax.servlet.ServletConfig` as parameter. It is a bad design but that's really the situation need to overcome.

Comment: @Trein I think the old API trying to consider all situation besides `HttpServlet` so it takes from bottom line? Which just stinks.

Comment: You still have to tell us where you need it injected.  Can you modify that class? Does it have a setter? Etc.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than autowiring, trying implementing [ServletConfigAware](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ServletConfigAware.html).

**Edit**:

I couldn't find an example that shows using ServletConfigAware in a real project.  Essentially, you'd have a class that implemented this interface to obtain the ServletConfig.
You'd create a Spring bean from the class by annotating the class with @Component or declaring a bean in XML.  When Spring creates the bean, it would invoke `setServletConfig(ServletConfig servletConfig)`.

Once you had an instance of ServletConfig in your bean, you'd do whatever you need with it.

Your question was how to obtain the ServletConfig, but I think (correct me if I'm wrong) you are looking to integrate a legacy Servlet into your Spring Web MVC application.   [ServletWrappingController](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/ServletWrappingController.html) might be a better choice.  I haven't ever used it myself, but it appears to be specifically designed for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks could you please be more specific with any extra resource?